# Kotlin: How to check fast if list2 contains one item of list1

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to check if a given list2 contains at least one item of given list1. If so, I would like to return true. My current approach is:

```
val object1 = Object1(body = listOf(1,2,3))
val object2 = Object1(body = listOf(2,5,7)

val doesList2ContainList1: Boolean = object2.body.intersect(object1.body).any() ==> should return true
```

I doubt that this is the fastest possible way to check if object2.body contains one item of object1.body because it checks the whole list, creates a new one and then executes any() right? But I want to instantly return true if one item of list2 is in list1. I have to make sure that this is really fast because object1.body and or object2.body can become really large.

I appreciate every help. Thank you

Comment: There is no way to check whether an item from one `List` is inside of another `List` if those lists are unsorted, under O(n^2) time. If you were to have them sorted, then this becomes O(n). If you happen to change your data structure to `Set` (or have one in addition to the `List`), then this also becomes O(n).

Comment: Couldn't I call list2.toSet() and then execute the code? Would this make it O(n)? I've checked it fast and executing the above code without .set() took 2.59 miliseconds, and with list1.toSet() and list2.toSet() it took 1.3 milisecond

Comment: Calling `toSet()` every time will introduce O(n) complexity. Then querying every element from a `List` to check whether it is present in the set will be O(n*log_n). Ultimately you will need O(n) additional space and O(n + n*log_n) time. By sorting the lists once you will once suffet the O(n*log_n) and querying will always be O(n), as opposed to your proposed O(n + n*log_n) evey time you look for duplicates.

Comment: So calling toSet() would only worsen my situation.. How can I achieve O(n) then? Just by sorting both lists and then comparing them? Could you provide a answer for this?

Comment: I don't think I can, since I still have too little information to provide a good solution, I believe. Does your `class` require that its `body`'s type has to be a `List`? Can it already be a `Set`?

Comment: No, it requires to be a list at the end. I can't change the body type to set since I am getting the list from my api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`intersect` internally uses a set, so `O(n)`. You can make it faster though (even though not with better time complexity), if performance is really a concern. For example:

```
fun <T> Collection<T>.containsAny(other: Collection<T>): Boolean {
    // Use HashSet instead of #toSet which uses a LinkedHashSet 
    val set = if (this is Set) this else HashSet(this)
    for (item in other)
        if (set.contains(item)) // early return
            return true
    return false
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you very much, it works. Does this also work when type of collection one and other are different?